# Django : Calling a Url with get method

Tags: django, django-views

I have the url and corresponding view as follows.

```
url(r'^(?P<token>.*?)/ack$', views.api_ACK, name='device-api_ack')

def api_ACK(request, token):
    """
    Process the ACK request comming from the device
    """
    logger.info('-> api_ACK', extra={'request': request, 'token' : token, 'url': request.get_full_path()})
    logger.debug(request)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # verify the request
        action, err_msg = api_verify_request(token=token, action_code=Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        return api_send_answer(action, err_msg)
```

I want to call `api_ACK` function with request method as GET from another view api_send_answer

I am creating one url in `/device/LEAB86JFOZ6R7W4F69CBIMVBYB9SFZVC/ack` in `api_send_answer` view as follows..

```
def api_send_answer(action, err_msg, provisional_answer=None):        

    last_action = create_action(session,action=Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE,token=last_action.next_token,timer=500)
    url = ''.join (['/device/',last_action.next_token ,'/',Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE])
    logger.debug('Request Url')
    logger.debug(url)
    response = api_ACK(request=url,token=last_action.next_token) # This is wrong
```

Now from `api_send_answer` it is redirecting to `api_ACK` view, but how to call `api_ACK` with request method as GET?

Please help..Any suggestions would be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

This line 
`response = api_ACK(request=url,token=last_action.next_token)` is wrong because view expects `HttpRequest` object and you give him url instead.

if you need to return view response to user, you can use redirect:

```
def api_send_answer(action, err_msg, provisional_answer=None):        

    last_action = create_action(session,action=Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE,token=last_action.next_token,timer=500)
    url = ''.join (['/device/',last_action.next_token ,'/',Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE])
    logger.debug('Request Url')
    logger.debug(url)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

if you need to do something else with view response you have to use `HttpRequest` object not url as parameter.